# Add hh:mm:ss to 12 hour time format

Tags: c

So for example the first input is 04:42:42 PM, and the second input is 07:53:59 output is 12:36:41 AM

Is there any error in my code?? I've tried to submit it, but it keeps showing me error. is there any other way to solve this question?? I genuinely don't know where I am wrong. I don't mind using either C or C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    int a, b, c;
    char str[5];
    scanf("%d:%d:%d %s", &a, &b, &c, str);

    int pmam = 0;
    if(strcmp(str, "AM") == 0){
        pmam = 1;
    }

    int d, e, f;
    scanf("%d:%d:%d", &d, &e, &f);

    c+=f;
    if(c >= 60){
        b++;
        c-=60;
    }

    b+=e;
    if(b >= 60){
        d++;
        b-=60;
    }

    int temp = a;
    a+=d;
    if(a >= 12 && d != 0 && temp != 12){
        pmam = (pmam == 1) ? 0 : 1;
    }
    while(a>12){
        a-=12;
    }

    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d ", a, b, c);
    (pmam == 1) ? printf("AM\n") : printf("PM\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you convert everything to minutes if that's the granularity needed? Adding minutes together should be straight forward.

Comment: Does this code work for all the text cases the programing site is giving you?  Does it tell you on which case it is failing?

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should be using `std::string` instead of character arrays.  Character arrays can overflow and if they don't have their terminating nul character, undefined behavior results.

Comment: No, it does not work for every text cases. and it doesn't tell me where it is incorrect either.

Comment: @bear Try to come up with tricky cases that you can bombard your program with. These are called test cases. We use them in real code all the time. When you find a case where your program doesn't work - brilliant - you've got something to debug.

Comment: In first step you should refactor code into multiple functions. For example create function which does only addition of time.

Comment: What's the largest value allowed for the second input? Can it be 12:34:00? Can it be 20:00:00?

Comment: @user3386109 the second intput can be up until 24:00:00. I have fixed that part, but it still incorrect.

Comment: If you changed the code, you should update the question with the new code.

Comment: @user3386109 sorry. This is my first time asking a question here. I'll update it swiftly.

Comment: Ok, so now you have a loop that reduces `a` until it's a number between 1 and 12. Assuming that works (I haven't tested it), all that's left is to get the AM/PM correct. You need to toggle between AM and PM every time 12 is subtracted from `a`.

Comment: So the `if` statement goes away, and toggle AM/PM inside the `while` loop. Btw, you can toggle a boolean with the logical negation operator: `pmam = !pmam;`

Comment: It might be easier to convert to a 24-hour format, do the arithmetic, and then convert back.

Comment: You should comment your code and use more meaningful variable names - having to explain the code to yourself by commenting it will help the design and find bugs; and better variable names will make it easier for you top follow.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is unnecessarily complex, and unsafe.  It can be simplified and made more robust.

The following solution works by calculating the sum of seconds then converting back to HH:MM:SS AM/PM.

It correctly handles time increments of more than 24 hours and normalises input so that it handles out of range input "sensibly". So for example adding `00:00:3600` will add one hour (3600 seconds).

By initialising the input variables and avoiding the use of a string buffer with no overrun protection, it is far more robust and will behave more gracefully when on incorrect input by behaving at least deterministically.
It does not validate the input, it simply behaves predictably when the input is invalid.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // Start time
    int thh = 0 ;
    int tmm = 0 ; 
    int tss = 0 ;
    char am_pm = 0 ;
    scanf("%d:%d:%d %cM", &thh, &tmm, &tss, &am_pm ) ;

    // Time increment
    int ihh = 0 ;
    int imm = 0 ;
    int iss = 0 ;
    scanf( "%d:%d:%d", &ihh, &imm, &iss ) ;

    // Normalise hours to 24 hour
    thh %= 12 ;                     // 00h to 11h
    if( am_pm == 'P' ) thh += 12 ;  // 00h to 23hh
    
    // Get sum in seconds
    int seconds = (thh + ihh) * 3600 + 
                  (tmm + imm) * 60 + 
                  (tss + iss) ;
    
    // Convert back to HH:MM:SS AM/PM
    tss = seconds % 60 ;
    tmm = (seconds / 60) % 60 ;
    thh = (seconds / 3600) % 12 ;
    if( thh == 0 ) thh = 12 ;
    am_pm = (seconds % 86400 >= 43200 ) ? 'P' : 'A' ;

    printf( "%02d:%02d:%02d %cM\n", thh, tmm, tss, am_pm );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about this part? I haven't run the code, but I don't think it does what you want it to do: `thh = (thh % 24 == 12 ) ? 12 : thh % 12` Also, this appears to suffer from lack of input validation just as the OP's code does. OP doesn't tell us if that's a requirement, but if their code is failing these unknown tests for that reason, this one will too.

Comment: @Caleb Input validation is an issue but perhaps not what the question is about. That is a trivial aspect the OP can address. Re the thh assignment,  what makes you thin that does not do what _I_ think it does? I have tested it; there may be test cases I have missed I suppose, but you need to be clearer about what you think is incorrect. It ensures that Noon is represented by 12 PM not 00 PM. Arithmetically the thh % 12 is always 0 to 11. It fixes the special non arithmetic case of noon.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for the explanation; I didn't quite grok your comment, but what you say makes sense. Even so, if `thh` is 0 e.g. if the time is between midnight and 1am, won't you end up assigning 0 instead of the 12 that you want? Seems like `thh = (thh % 12 == 0) ? 12 : thh % 12` would fix that. Also, I think you'll want to move the next line, setting `am_pm` up above the line that changes `thh`, else you'll always get PM when `thh` is 12 and AM otherwise. The validation concern goes to OP's question about why their program might have been rejected.

Comment: @user3386109 : You are right.  I have retested both your original and edited code, and cannot reproduce.  Cannot explain that, but the results were copy and pasted from the test I performed.  I have to assume operator error on my part.

Comment: @Caleb ; Doh!  I was using 24 hour clock convention for "zero hour" rather then 12AM / 12PM.  Regarding validation, I did ask in a question comment whether input validation is required - no answer.  However here by initialising the input variables, and normalising the input, there are few user input errors that this won't handle gracefully.  Without a verbatim statement of the problem and rules, who can tell?

Comment: Rewritten solution - previous comments refer to previous solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I genuinely don't know where I am wrong.

What happens when you put in invalid data? `99:99:99`? `1500:23.6:-2`? `abc:def:ghi`?

You've got a bunch of uninitialized variables and no input validation. Lack of a length specifier in the format string for at least the AM/PM part means that input like `06:00:00 ALL_YOUR_BASE_ARE_BELONG_TO_US` will overflow your 5-character buffer and probably crash your program.

It's a good bet that some of the tests used to check your program give it inputs that you're not expecting.

Answer (score -1):

Converting to seconds everything is simplier than calculating the reminder and carry it on.

Here's what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct time {
    unsigned int hh : 5; //max 5 bits, < 32
    unsigned int mm : 6; //max 6 bits, < 64
    unsigned int ss : 6; //max 6 bits, < 64
};

long time_to_long_ss_only (struct time t) {
    return t.ss + 60* (t.mm + 60*t.hh);
}

struct time long_ss_only_to_time (long s) {
    struct time t;
    long first = s;
    long next = first/60;
    t.ss = first - next*60;
    first = next;
    next /= 60;
    t.mm = first - next*60;
    first = next;
    next /= 24;
    t.hh = first - next*24;
    return t;
};

struct time add_time (struct time a, struct time b) {
    return long_ss_only_to_time(time_to_long_ss_only(a) + time_to_long_ss_only(b));
}

int main () {
    struct time a = {23, 42, 42}, b = {00, 59, 59};
    struct time c = add_time(a, b);
    printf("%i:%i:%i\n", c.hh, c.mm, c.ss);
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that I used bitfields to reduce memory footprint as much as possible. I suggest to rename the struct to something more specific (eg `struct time_hh_mm_ss` as time structs consider dates as well).

This method works with 24h cycles and doesn't break if the 2 times end up "overflowing" in the next day when added.

Comment: The amount of extra code the compiler has to generate to manipulate bitfields will most likely out-weight any tiny saving of using them.  It is an irrelevant issue in this question, and just a distraction.   Also the question calls for 12 hour clock.

Comment: Implementing the 12h to 24h code has already been done by you the best and easiest way possible, probably. Talking about the bitfields: I overuse them, my bad! That said, the idea of converting everything to seconds looks much simplier, to me at least.

Comment: The OP's explanation of the problem is too vague, but I think the main think they're asking is why their solution was rejected, whether there's something wrong with it, etc. Your answer converts HH:mm:ss times to 24-hour format instead of requested 12-hour, and you've entirely skipped the input part that allows the program to be tested with different inputs. I'd guess this program wouldn't be accepted by the validator either. It's hard to understand your "Please note..." statement when bitfields and memory use are orthogonal to the problem. WHY? **TL/DR:** What's wrong with the OP's code?